# CSS3 Transitions - skills bubble thing?

Tags: css, transition

I really would love to know how to do this effect here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtG8w7_C0TI&feature=youtu.be

In the video i click one (still in the screen recording window), but they work via hover.

Could some point to something that will help me understand more about the effect i pretty sure this is it http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

and if it is, i guess i use "border-radius:" to make a div into a circle then just align them how i wish using css (like how you would a div)

Is this how or is there a simpler way? or a jQuery plugin or something else.

Sorry for my lack of technical terms.... and thanks for reading, any help with be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use `border-radius` with a value of 50% to create a circle;

2) You can enlarge your element using `CSS3 transform`;

3) You can delay the enlargement using `CSS3 transition`;

**Working demo** (in FireFox):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmtCW/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="circle">
    <br/>I'm a circle
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle{
    margin: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: darkkhaki;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden; 
}

.circle:hover{    
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Use the amazing [CSS3 Generator](http://css3generator.com/) to create your cross-browser code.

Good luck